# Transforming an overlaid transparent div into an image of its background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know if it's possible to perform the mentioned operation because currently there is no possible way for JavaScript to 'see' the contents of some objects e.g. Flash video player. I've looked at a lot of screenshot plugins but none of them works in my favour.

Would it be necessary to create a new plugin/extension from scratch?

*This operation will only be performed on the client-side*

An example of what I would like to achieve:

```
div1 : .......... (transparent)
div2 : __________
```

*after*

```
div1': __________ (copy)
div2 : __________
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that would work is the HTML5 canvas element.

A page could make a snapshot of itself, put it into a `canvas` element, extract the image in BASE-64 encoded form and post it with AJAX to the server without asking the user permission to do so.

This is considered a vulnerability. Therefor `getImageData()` on a `canvas` element has restrictions and browser vendors try to protect their customers by enforcing these and other restrictions.

Some more info here: [grabbing cross-domain images](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I followed the example code in this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp) and it appears that the canvas element does not work for objects.

I am trying to capture a single frame of a live stream so my code looks something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7qHpT/). All that appears is a blank box. I am suspecting that it's because the video player takes some time to load. Do you think it would make a difference if I create a button to fire the `getImageData()`?

Comment: I don't really know. I just wanted to tell you about why some things are not possible: there are security constraints to be considered.